# CSS. Center block on the mobile devices

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/2r4bzjqe/

First of all I need to display this block (without static width, because it will be displayed on various mobile devices) in the center of page.

And I need to display this ul list in one vertical line, so second li should start on the same place that first li. I can't use static width, text-align: left and margin: 0 auto, because it should work for any mobile devices.

Current situation:

```
  Test

  Test Test
    Test
  Test Test
```

I need this for not fixed screen width:

```
  Test

  Test Test
  Test
  Test Test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**//EDIT:** 
i updated this so your text block is now centered within a parent container. you would have to use a parent container for this solution with the following css

```css
.test {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block
    
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="test">
    <div>
        Test
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>Test Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test Test</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

since `ul` has a standard padding you should remove that

Comment: Sorry, but issue not in ul padding. I forgot to mention that block should be on the center of the page.

Answer (score 1):

normally there should be a reset.css first (resets all default element behaviors), I did the minimum first instead of reset.css, and then you may use the following css

```
* {margin:0; padding:0;} /*use reset.css here*/

.test {
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align:left;
    display: inline-block; /*this does the trick*/
}
```

Comment: u r welcome :-). Additional note: display inline-block resizes the ul to the width of the longest li, and centeres itself by the text-align center of the div. This may result in different positions/widths of ul. If you want the ul in the same position and size, you can set the li to a fixed width like --> li {width: 200px}... or so